# Parse Cloud Function: Change object attributes before return

Tags: javascript, ios, parse-platform

I have Parse _User's with sensitive data on them, so I have the ACL's for Public Read/Write set to false. However, I want to allow users to get *some* of the user's data, such as their first/last name. I'm doing this through cloud code - where they poll for a user with a specific objectId, but when the cloud code returns, it will censor the sensitive data by changing the fields before it returns to the user. However, it appears that Parse considers this returning of objects "dirty," and refuses to return. Is there a way to return modified objects to users in this fashion (or any other fashion)?

For example, my user object has five (notable) fields.

```
+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+----------+
| objectId | firstName | lastName | birthdate | username |
+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+----------+
| aBcDeFgH | "Jason"   | "Bourne" | "4/15/71" | jbourne  |
+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+----------+
```

When I have it queried, I want to omit the birthdate. To do this in the cloud, I say something along the lines of...

```
var object = result // result of a Parse.Query.first function
object.set("birthdate", "censored")
return object
```

And I get the following error.

```
[Error]: Uncaught Tried to save an object with a pointer to a new, unsaved object. (Code: 141, Version: 1.8.2)
```

Comment: Did you try to use the master key?

Comment: I use the `Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey()` command to poll the server to bypass the ACL's - that isn't the problem. The problem occurs when I try to return an unsaved PFObject to the user without saving the PFObject - saving the PFObject would overwrite the fields that are still utilized.

Comment: Could you post the code? After 2000 lines of Cloud Code I built up a bit of experience ^^ Anyway you shouldn't return unsaved Parse Objects (please don't call them PFObjects unless you're talking about obj-c/swift code lol)

Comment: Force of habit. Updated original post with snippits.

Comment: [This answer](https://www.parse.com/questions/modifying-response-in-cloud-code) (the first one) from their forum might help you

Comment: This is the point: You can't return an unsaved object (it wouldn't make much sense). This is what I think you should do: create another Class containing objects that only the user should see, and put a pointer referring to user, each user should have 1 object. I did something like this for a game I'm making, where users have their own stats, and while a user can edit its attributes, he can't edit its stats (or a client could power up ranks, XP, ecc.)

Comment: The user class should become again public readable if it doesn't contain anymore sensitive data

Comment: @Alladinian - throw that response into an answer and I'll give you credit for the answer. Thanks user1714647 for your suggestions - that would work, but it's just a little more trouble than I really want to go through for these purposes.

Comment: @ChrisMartin Done. Glad that helped you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[There is (a quite old, but still applicable) answer](https://www.parse.com/questions/modifying-response-in-cloud-code) in their forum.

The idea behind this is that since Parse prohibits unsaved (persistent) objects to be returned to the client, you just copy the object, edit the copy and return that instead. I hope that this makes sense.

Comment: can you provide code? Copy an object is not clear. Do you mean you return an actual parse object or you return a JSON. Thanks